# Can anyone help me - how to use arrays in opensearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I put an object with some field and i wanna figure out how to mapping the index to handle and show the values like elasticsearch. I dunno why opensearch separate to individual fields the values. Both app has the same index mappings but the display is different for something.

[image: Elastic data display]

[image: Opensearch data display]

I tried to map the object type set to nested but nothing changes

```
PUT test
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "szemelyek": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "szam": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "nev": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand, but in OpenSearch, for an array, you can use this as the body to create an index that stores an Array for "weekday":

```
stack_array = {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "array_id": {"type": "integer"},
            "weekday": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "dayShort":{"type": "text"},
                    "dayLong": {"type": "tex"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above will return an array with for example

```
{'array_id': 1, 'weekday': ['Sun', 'Sunday']}}
```

The items in the array are of the same type (Arrays in OpenSearch can only store values of one type).